# Set Primary category using the Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: php, wp-insert-post, save-post, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

```
function set_primary_on_publish ($post_id) {
    global $post; 

    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ); 
    // wrapper to hide any errors from top level categories or products without category
    if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 

        // loop through each cat
        foreach($categories as $category) :
          // get the children (if any) of the current cat
          $children = get_categories( array ('taxonomy' => 'category', 'parent' => $category->term_id ));

          if ( count($children) == 0 ) {

                $childid = $category->term_id;
                update_post_meta($post->ID,'_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',$childid);

          }
        endforeach;

    endif;

    }
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_primary_on_publish', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'edit', 'set_primary_on_publish', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_primary_on_publish', 10, 2 );
```

I'm trying to save the deepest child category as the primary category in the Yoast SEO plugin however the above doesn't seem to do the job.

Anyone who can help me out on this?

Best regards,
Dylan Smit

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want, what's the erroneous/actual behaviour of this code?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead

```
update_post_meta($post->ID,'_yoast_wpseo_primary_category',$childid);
```

Use below function:

```
function wpseoPrimaryTerm($taxonomy, $postID, $term){

  if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') ) {
  // Set primary term.
  $primaryTermObject = new WPSEO_Primary_Term($taxonomy, $postID);
  $primaryTermObject->set_primary_term($term);

  // Save primary term.
  $primaryTermObjectAdmin = new WPSEO_Primary_Term_Admin();
  $primaryTermObjectAdmin->save_primary_terms($postID);
  }else{
    echo 'Class WPSEO does not exit';
  }
}
```

Where `$taxonomy - taxonomy name, $PostID - $post->ID, $term - $childid`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `product` to `product_cat` and `_yoast_wpseo_primary_category` to `_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat` for it to work. When saving or updating a product it will grab the deepest `product_id` and set it as the `product_id` in the `wp_postmeta` table.

```php
function set_primary_on_publish ($post_ID) {
    global $post;

    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ); 

    // wrapper to hide any errors from top level categories or products without category
    if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) :

        // loop through each cat
        foreach($categories as $category) :

          // get the children (if any) of the current cat
          $children = get_categories( array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent' => $category->term_id ));

          if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
                $childid = $category->term_id;
                update_post_meta($post->ID,'_yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat',$childid);
          }
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Did not you mean "to change `'category'`  into `'product_cat'` and ..."?